# Spring boot health check on existing webapp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have existing Spring MVC web application. Now I just want to use the health check feature present in spring-boot-starter-actuator.

I am new to spring boot, so not sure if I need to convert my complete project to spring boot project for health check to work. Can I just include the dependency and somehow enable only the required feature?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Instead of `spring-boot-starter-actuator` I am including `spring-boot-actuator`. And I don't need to initialize the application using `@SpringBootApplication`. Instead now I just import the auto-config classes that are required. So the config class now looks like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.example" })
@Import({MyApplicationContext.class, EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, 
  ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class, EndpointAutoConfiguration.class, 
  HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebApplicationContext {
...
}
```

`EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration` depends on `ManagementServerProperties` hence had to import it. This seems to be the bare minimum configuration for me. Let me know if there is any better alternative

Comment: You can also import `PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class` to get jvm/threads metrics available at _/metrics_ endpoint

Comment: How to monitor such non spring-boot application using spring-boot-admin ?

Comment: Didn't worked for me. I'm running spring webapp using gretty plugin. any extra configurations needed ??

Answer (score 7):

First of all I'd like tell that [sidgate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387971/616290) is correct. 
But maybe somebody need to enable all metrics or choose different set of metrics.

You still can use `spring-boot-starter-actuator` instead of `spring-boot-actuator`

**For enabling all metrics**

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
@org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementContextConfiguration
public class MyApplicationContext {
}
```

where `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.AuditAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CacheStatisticsAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.InfoContributorAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.JolokiaAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsChannelAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricExportAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.TraceRepositoryAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.TraceWebFilterAutoConfiguration.class
```

and `@ManagementContextConfiguration`

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration
```

enables Spring Boot Configurations

**For enabling certain management endpoints** you could import endpoint's configurations directly as [sidgate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387971/616290)'s already explained

```
@Configuration
@Import({
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.AuditAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CacheStatisticsAutoConfiguration.class,

...

})
public class MyApplicationContext {
}
```

**P.S.** Of course Spring Application Context and Properties initialization could be configured as always via annotations or xml configuration.

Answer (score 3):

If smb is looking for a configuration of Spring Boot Actuator 2.x in an existing Spring MVC project, this is a configuration which worked for me

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,

        InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        ServletManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
        ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CorsEndpointProperties.class)
class ActuatorConfiguration {

    @Bean //taken from WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
                                                                         WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(webEndpointProperties.getBasePath());
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
                corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(),
                new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, webEndpointProperties.getBasePath()));
    }

    @Bean
    DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath() {
        return () -> "/";
    }

}
```

I did include

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

for compatibility with the baseline Spring version I've been using (5.1.19.RELEASE)

Comment: For versions > 2.2.0 you should replace `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class` with `HealthContributorAutoConfiguration`
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Thanks Jakub and Denis. I had a legacy application using spring webmvc 5.x and I was struggling to get actuator working. I was able to use the version 2.5.13, adding false to the latest param of WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping constructor