# spring-boot-actuator not working with non spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am new to spring boot and is trying to make actuator work in my spring webmvc **without @SpringBootApplication**. But could not access the health endpoint or any endpoints.  I keep on getting a 404 error. What am i missing ?
Here is my code -- 
pom.xml`

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>NewSpringMVC</groupId>
  <artifactId>NewSpringMVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>4.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>`
```

Java class--

```html
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.InfoEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@Import({EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.latestmvc.controller"})
public class SpringBootActuatorConfig {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> endpoints) {
        return new EndpointHandlerMapping(endpoints);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EndpointMvcAdapter metricsEndPoint(InfoEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint(HealthEndpoint delegate) {
        return new HealthMvcEndpoint(delegate);
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: servlet.xml-- 
 
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.latestmvc.controller" />
<bean id="viewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"
value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Actuator without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953157/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot)

Comment: @AmitP, The solution in the link works for me, but thats with SpringBootApplication. Here I am trying to implement without that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this i think : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384685/spring-boot-health-check-on-existing-webapp/33387971#33387971

Comment: @RafikBELDI, I was following the solution provided in the link you provided, but its not working. So I asked this question trying to figure what mistake I made