# Spring Boot 2 Actuator without Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to add Spring Boot actuator metrics to my existing Spring MVC 5 application (I cannot convert to Spring Boot).
There are a couple of answered questions on SO ([Spring Boot Actuator without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953157/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot)) but they are for using Spring Boot Actuator 1.x.
Spring Boot Actuator 2.x has been re-architected and so these instructions are no longer valid.
Has anyone integrated Spring Boot Actuator 2.x with a standard Spring MVC 5 app?

Comment: check similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953157/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot) Hope it helps

Comment: If you look at my post you will see that I already referenced that link and said that it is only for Spring Boot Actuator 1.x

Comment: @PiersGeyman I also want to use "Spring Boot 2 Actuator" module without Spring Boot, any workarounds which worked for you?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot include Spring Boot Actuator without requiring Spring Boot. Spring Boot is a Maven dependency of the Spring Boot Actuator project (the name also suggests that spring boot is required).

You can check out [the actual dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/pom.xml#L21) of spring-boot in the pom of spring-boot-actuator.

Comment: I think the first actuator was also depending on spring boot but it still could be used in old spring applications, so I don't think your answer is 100% correct. (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-actuator/pom.xml)

Comment: `spring-boot` was also a dependency in version 1.x but the actuator could still be used.