# Actuator not working with non spring boot application

Tags: spring, http-status-code-404, spring-boot-actuator

I have an existing Spring Application, and I am trying to bind actuator to it. With available examples and documentation, I have added dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have added below configurations in my servlet.xml

```
  <bean id="endpointAutoConfiguration" class="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration"/>
  <bean id="publicMetricsAutoConfiguration" class="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration"/>
  <bean id="healthIndicatorAutoConfiguration" class="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration"/>
```

With following configurations

```
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.health.id=health
endpoints.health.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
server.port=8080
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
endpoints.logfile.enabled=true
```

While debugging, I have seen that in class `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint` 3 classes are picked up for health indicator `DataSourceHealthIndicator`, `DiskSpaceHealtIndicator` and `JmsHealthIndicator` and the details it picked are correct for autowired instances.

While enabling springframework logs in DEBUG mode, I saw below lines in log for many properties related to actuator

```
07:04:01,302 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1]: JndiLocatorDelegate  ReqId:() DFReqId:() - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/endpoints.health.enabled] not found - trying original name [endpoints.health.enabled]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [endpoints.health.enabled] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [endpoints.health.enabled].
```

Not getting the pointer, what I am missing.

Getting 404 exception on http://localhost:8080/health, http://localhost:8080/info

Comment: See here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953157/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot