# Implement actuator in any JAX-RS project

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot provides a utility called actuator which gives several useful maintenance endpoints like 
/beans , /metrics , /health , /trace , /info, /dump.

This insight is vital for monitoring. By default Spring Actuator functionality is accessible via Spring MVC.

For projects which are not using Spring, like any JAX RS implementation (ours is RESTEASY), Is it possible to somehow integrate these utilities or is there reference implementation that can be referred?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953157/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot Looks like you can possibly use it without Spring Boot itself but you still need the Spring web stack.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I checked it and it seems I will need the Spring stack to make it happen.