# Expose cache endpoint from spring-boot-actuator in not a non spring-boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I am using non spring-boot app but I need to expose endpoint which will return caches configured in the application. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953157/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot) post but it is for spring-boot-actuator version 1.X and I am using spring-boot-actuator version 2.1.3.RELEASE as the cache endpoint is available in this version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to the application.yml file?

```
management:endpoints.web.exposure.include: ["caches", etc....`]
management.endpoint.caches.enabled:true
```

Comment: Yes tried that but when I do http://localhost:8080/caches it gives 404.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set actuator endpoint?

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path // default /actuator
```

In that case, you should include endpoint to the path.
example

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/caches
```