# How to configure Springboot's 2.x actuator in Spring Application(not a SpringBoot Application)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

My application is using Spring and not SpringBoot but I would like to perform health check using SpringBoot's 2.x Actuator. Did this combination ever work for any?

Comment: Its a kind of "grey area". Something can work, but this is not a "supported path". Check this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953157/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot

Comment: @MarkBramnik Do we have the latest SpringBoot(>= 2.x) support?

Comment: I can't say for sure, again its not the "well-known" path - you should try yourself.