# how to deploy Spring boot actuate application in external tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Im trying to just use the basic endpoints that comes with spring actuate and want to deploy in the external tomcat server without using spring boot. How to achieve this, could anyone help me please. Is there any configuration changes that I need to do. [This website gives an idea](http://www.leveluplunch.com/blog/2013/12/22/configure-spring-actuator-outside-of-spring-boot/) but it uses older version of spring-boot-actuate. Also EndpointHandlerMapping and EndpointHandlerAdapter doesnt come with newer version of spring boot actuate.

Anyways I get 404 resource not found when deploying to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913087/use-spring-boot-actuator-without-a-spring-boot-application) to see if it helps you.  The Actuator component is a Spring Boot feature but you can use individual components within an existing application with the right build and configuration setups.