# how to get metrics from spring-boot-actuator programmatically?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

we have a spring application in production. It is NOT Spring-boot. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913087/use-spring-boot-actuator-without-a-spring-boot-application) on how to use spring-boot-actuator in a non-spring-boot application.

However, the requirement for us is to aggregate the data from /metrics endpoint and do some analytics on it and report a status indicator.

For eg, we might use heap parameter such as
`{"heap.committed":480768,"heap.init":262144,"heap.used":294461,"heap":3728384,"threads.peak":37}` to indicate the status of the application - FATAL, WARN or HEALTHY.

This is just an example. our requirement is more complex. In-fact, we already have a `status endpoint` where we want to add more info (based on data from `/metrics` and `/health` endpoints of `spring-boot-actuator`).

One way I am thinking of acheiving this is 
making REST call to `/metrics` and `/health` with-in the application, collect the data, aggregate them and return the response. I don't think it is a recommended way.

If there is a bean where I could extract these parameters directly, I would autowire it and calculate them on the fly as and when needed. (In fact, I will schedule to calculate periodically).

I am interested in all the attributes returned from `/metrics`.
while I am also interested in the following from `/health`.

```
{"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","free":386186194944,"threshold":10485760}}
```

what beans should I autowire and get these attributes for free!

Thanks

**EDIT**

This [post](http://kielczewski.eu/2015/01/application-metrics-with-spring-boot-actuator/) has `@Autowired MetricRepository`. But for some reason, it returning only the custom counter properties. It is NOT returning heap, memory info etc
Eg:

`Reporting metric counter.calls.get_greeting=4
Reporting metric counter.calls.get_greeting.1=1
Reporting metric counter.calls.get_greeting.2=1
Reporting metric counter.calls.get_greeting.3=1
Reporting metric counter.calls.get_greeting.4=1
Reporting metric counter.status.200.greeting.number=4
Reporting metric counter.status.404.star-star=1`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The output from `/metrics` is produced by `MetricsEndpoint`. It's available as a bean that you can have `@Autowired`. Calling `invoke` on it should give you the data that you want.

You can do the same for `/health` with `HealthEndpoint`.

Comment: Getting null if I auto-wire MetricsEndpoint any other step needs to be done? What is calling invoke ?