# How to have spring boot metrics export averages and absolute values to csv

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, codahale-metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I need to export counters and gauges to csv in order to process them later on. By using gradle I get the jars for codahale metrics 3.1.2:

```
compile('io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:${metricsVersion}' )
compile('io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotations:${metricsVersion}' )
```

For the csv export I created one reporter using these lines of code:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Bean
    public CsvReporter configureReporters() {
        CsvReporter reporter = CsvReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry).build(new File("C:/temp/metrics"));
        reporter.start(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return reporter;
    }
}
```

I can see files are created and they contain a timestamp and value (in this example the values were set for a gauge):

```
1444137261,42.0
1444137266,42.0
1444137271,42.0
1444137276,1.0
1444137281,1.0
1444137286,1.0
```

The only problem with this is that the file repeats the last value set until it is overwritten by me using `gaugeService.submit()`. In this scenario I set a gauge value of `42.0` once, waited several minutes and then set a new value of `1.0`.

This makes it difficult to parse the csv and create averages on my own or create histograms because I don't know if the `42.0` was submitted once or three times.

I had a look at these SO posts but they didn't help me solve my problem:

- [Exporting Spring Boot Actuator Metrics (& Dropwizard Metrics) to Statsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215723/exporting-spring-boot-actuator-metrics-dropwizard-metrics-to-statsd)
- [how to get metrics from spring-boot-actuator programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382349/how-to-get-metrics-from-spring-boot-actuator-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this was based on a misunderstanding from my side: the metrics offered by Spring Boot only allow to use a [`gauge`](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/core/#man-core-gauges) or [`counters`](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/core/#man-core-counters). For both no averages are calculated.

In order to access what I need I have to gain access to the underlying Codahale metrics registry:

```
@Autowired
MetricRegistry metricRegistry;
```

Then I can start and stop a timer in my code:

```
Context timer = metricRegistry.timer("foo").time();
// do whatever needs to be timed
timer.stop();
```

These values will be exported by the CsvReporter in a file named `timer.foo.csv` which contains these values:

```
t,count,max,mean,min,stddev,p50,p75,p95,p98,p99,p999,mean_rate,m1_rate,m5_rate,m15_rate,rate_unit,duration_unit
1446036738,5,18,597084,14,172184,12,832516,2,145484,13,280135,13,445525,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,0,215907,0,494353,0,577132,0,592274,calls/second,milliseconds
1446036798,5,18,597084,14,172184,12,832516,2,145484,13,280135,13,445525,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,0,060092,0,181862,0,472516,0,554077,calls/second,milliseconds
1446036858,5,18,597084,14,172184,12,832516,2,145484,13,280135,13,445525,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,0,034923,0,066903,0,386863,0,518343,calls/second,milliseconds
1446036918,5,18,597084,14,172184,12,832516,2,145484,13,280135,13,445525,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,18,597084,0,024578,0,024612,0,316737,0,484913,calls/second,milliseconds
```