# Does having spring-boot-actuator changes the context root of the spring application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913087/use-spring-boot-actuator-without-a-spring-boot-application), by having the `spring-boot-actuator` dependency in `pom.xml`, I could benefits from the `actuator` endpoints. However, I observed it breaks my existing my spring application (It is not a spring-boot application).

I added the following to my dependency in pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
```

Thats it. I did not make any changes to application yet.
I started the container using `maven-t7-plugin`.
Now my application endpoint `http://localhost:8010/mycontext/foo` is returning 404. I commented out the above `dependency` in `pom.xml`.
Now my application returns `200 OK` for the above request.

Kindly help troubleshoot me as what is going wrong. I could not find any obvious reasons.

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't change the context, rather maybe it somehow expects your page to be in other place? Maybe it enables spring boot web. Show us some code.

Comment: I suspect actuator won't function very well with it not being a spring-boot application.

Comment: @ACV. I tried on our production code. I can't share it here. But it is straightforward to test it. meanwhile I will put some simple code here

Comment: @spencergibb: is it possible it breaks existing application just by having dependency in it?

Comment: @brain storm, what is the actual value for foo ?

Comment: Unless you're component scanning the actuator's packages, just adding it as a dependency to a non-Boot app should have no effect. As ACV said, I think you're going to have to show some code

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: I suppose the problem is from  `maven-t7-plugin`

Answer (score 2):

When I looked at the spring logs in console, I noticed the following:
`WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mycontext/foo] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'`.

Since I have configured `DispatcherServlet` in my Spring application, I cannot use `auto-configure` of `spring-boot-actuator`.

Once I excluded that `dependency`, my application works as expected.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```