# How to convert spring-boot web application to non-web application

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring-boot web application and it doesn't contain any rest end points and it only reads data by using kafka consumer. So i want convert it to non-web spring-boot application and i want to add spring batch configuration to this application.

I try to set the below configuration to make non-web application.

> spring.main.web-application-type=NONE

But i am getting the below error when i am running the application.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' in your configuration.
```

I would like to know what are the possible ways to convert spring-boot web application to non-web application.

And also i would like know is there any way to get info from /actuator end point after converting spring-boot web application to non-web application.

I tried 3rd suggetion in this document  [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-no-web-server) but i am unable get response from any api end point like from /actuator.

Comment: you will have to remove the spring boot web dependency as well from pom.xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Spring Boot Actuator without a Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913087/use-spring-boot-actuator-without-a-spring-boot-application)